# WPF TaskbarIcon ContextMenu

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu, messagebox

I'm trying to create an WPF application with TaskbarIcon,
I suppose if I click the icon in the traybar, it will popup a Contextmenu, 
and if I select "Exit", then it will show a messagebox asking me whether I want to close this app or not.

Here's the problem, the MessageBox show correctly, but it just disappear IMMEDIATELY BEFORE I click ANY button, and I use debugger to check the "Result" value, I found it's always "No". Does any encounter this problem before? Any single clue would be appreciated!!

Here's my .xaml code:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="WpfTaskIcon" IconSource="/Themes/Images/TimeSync.ico"
                    ToolTipText="Hello world" >
<tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu Background="LightCoral">
    <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="Exit_Click" />
    <MenuItem Header="Second menu Item" />
</ContextMenu>
</tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
```

and Here's my c# code:

```
private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
       "Message_ConfirmationOfExit",
        "Title_Confirmation",
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

edt : 
I've add this to initialize the visibility of MainWindow :

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    MessageBox.Show("MainWindow loaded");
    MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
       "Message_ConfirmationOfExit",
        "Title_Confirmation",
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was encountering this problem in other WPF scenarios and the cause was that **there was no main UI thread launched yet**. If you call `MessageBox()` or `MsgBox()` or VB `InputBox()` without main UI thread launched (=before first form of application is loaded), expected dialog box opens, but vanishes within a second. However, it creates missing UI thread by itself (I suppose... I did not check all the details) because on repeated calls of the same code the message box won't vanish any more.

**The solution** was to let the first form initialize (typically the main form) before opening of any message box. Invisible initialization counts, too.

Checklist question:

- was the any form of the application loaded (its Load event called)?

**A workaround** (not nice but works): if you do not have time for greater changes of the app, store current time before you display your **first** message box and if you get the reply back within 1500 ms, do not act upon its result (it was not from the user anyway) but re-display the message box again.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your advice and hint. However, I've add the segment to initialize the visibility of the MainWindow in "MainWindow_Loaded" before I invoke the "Exit_Click", and the code I've update is showed in the main particle. Although both of the hint and the confirm messagebox would show correctly, the confirmation box in "Exit_Click" stll vanish...

Comment: @Alanight – could you please try one alternative?  instead of putting the message box code into `_Loaded`, put it into `_Shown`.

Comment: I add MainWinow_Showen() method and invoke it right away after InitializeComponent(), the MessageBox showed correctly as usual, but the problem still exist... Here's my MainWindow_Showen method :
private void Main_Showen()
{
    this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

Comment: @Alanight – OK, then I admit I don't know. Maybe someone else gives you better answer here. You can still use a workaround shown in my answer, although such an approach is not the best.

Comment: OK! Thanks alot! I'll try to work this annoying problem out! Very appreciate for your help and avices!

Comment: Hi! miroxlav, in MainWindow_Loaded method, I let the thread sleep 1,500 milliseconds after the messagebox showed up, but the problem was still there.

Comment: @Alanight - the idea was:  (1) save current time (2) display messagebox (3) if you get reply from message box and this is your first message box since app launch, check time difference. If it is under 1500ms, re-display the message box again. Subsequent message boxes displayed do not have the issue

Comment: Oh~ I see! Sorry for misunderstanding what you meant! I will try it right away!

Comment: Wow! The problem was fixed!! Although the first MessageBox will still show up, it vanish instantly, and the subsequent MessageBox will perform  exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It may come a little too late, but I may have figured out the cause of this problem:

The `MessageBox` use a WindowAPI.

Reference: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MessageBox.html

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet= CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
```

The parameters include the `hWnd` of type `IntPtr`.

When `MessageBox.Show()` is called in WPF, the `ShowCore()` method is called inside the `MessageBox` class, which internally handles this parameter.

Reference: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/MessageBox.cs at line 483

```
...


if ( (options & (MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification | MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly)) ! = 0) 
{
    // Demand UnmangedCode permissions if using ServiceNotification/DefaultDesktopOnly.
    // Details in DevDiv 163043.
    SecurityHelper.DemandUnmanagedCode()
    if (owner ! = IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.Get(SRID.CantShowMBServiceWithOwner));
    }                
}
else
{                                    
    if (owner == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        owner = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow();
    }                
}

...
```

I think, when using `MessageBox` in WPF, the currently active window is automatically selected as the `hWnd`, and since there is no window, the `ContextMenu` is used as the window.

We can prove this using the API:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
```

And use it in click event:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = GetActiveWindow();
}
```

Then find the `t` value in spy++, is the `ContextMenu`.

When the `MenuItem` on the `ContextMenu` is clicked, the `ContextMenu` will be closed, at that time the owner of `MessageBox` disappears and `MessageBox` is forced to be closed.

Based on the above research, I got the following solutions.

1.Delay the appearance of the MessageBox so that it is displayed after the ContextMenu is closed.

```
await Task.Delay(200); 
MessageBox.Show("Hello, world!");
```

2.Call the API itself and set hWnd to IntPtr.Zero.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
```

and

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "Hello, world!", "Test", 0);
}
```

3.Modify the value of MessageBoxOptions according to the source code of MessageBox in WPF.

```
MessageBox.Show(
    "Hello, world!",
    "Test",
    MessageBoxButton.OK,
    MessageBoxImage.Error,
    MessageBoxResult.OK,
    MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification | MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
```

Maybe this can provide some help for everyone.

==================

I think this way is better:

Add a variable to App.xaml.cs:

```
bool isNeedShowMessageBox = false;
```

When the MenuItem is pressed:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isNeedShowMessageBox = true;
}
```

Add event for ContextMenu:

```
<ContextMenu Closed="ContextMenu_Closed">
```

Then:

```
private void ContextMenu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isNeedShowMessageBox)
    {
        MessageBox.Show();
        isNeedShowMessageBox=false;
    }
}
```

This seems to be working just fine.

In subsequent attempts I found that not only MessageBox, but also OpenFileDialog or other similar windows would have the same forced closure, but if handled in this way, the problem should be avoided.